# machine-learning, neural-network,classifier, wrong output with same results for all output,python

Tags: python, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp
from numpy import random
from numpy import log
from numpy import size
from numpy import amax
from numpy import multiply as mul
from numpy import vstack
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1+ exp(-x) )


def backPro(X,y,alpha):

    a1=X.T
    n1=size(X,1)
    n2=10
    m=size(a1,1)
    a1 = vstack((np.ones((1,m)), a1))
    K=size(y,0)

    Jlist=[]
    s=100
    lit=0

    #initialization (radonize)
    theta1=random.rand(n2,n1+1)
    theta2=random.rand(K,n2+1)

    while lit<10000:
        z2 = theta1 * a1
        a2 = sigmoid(z2)
        a2 = vstack((np.ones((1,m)), a2))
        z3 = theta2 * a2
        H = sigmoid(z3)

        J = (-1.0/m) * np.sum(mul(y,log(H)) + mul(1-y,log(1-H)))

        Jlist.append(J)

        sigma3 = H-y
        sigma2 = mul( (theta2.T * sigma3), mul(a2 , (1-a2)) )

        delta1 = sigma2[1:] * a1.T * (1.0/m)
        delta2 = sigma3 * a2.T * (1.0/m)

        #do the gradient descent
        theta1 -= (delta1 * alpha)
        theta2 -= (delta2 * alpha)

        #update the s
        #s=max( amax(np.abs(delta1)),amax(np.abs(delta2)) )
        lit+=1

    plot.scatter(range(0,len(Jlist)),Jlist,1)
    plot.scatter(range(0,len(Jlist[-100:])), Jlist[-100:],1)

    print "The J is "+str(J)
    print "The S is "+str(s)
    print "lit is "+str(lit)

    return theta1,theta2


def cost(a1,y,h):
    m=size(a1,0)

    Kmatrix=np.sum( mul(y, log(h)) + mul((1-y), log(1-h)) )
    J= (-1.0/m)* Kmatrix

    return J

def predict(X, theta1, theta2):
    X = X.T
    m = size(X,1)
    X = vstack((np.ones((1,m)),X))

    hidden = sigmoid(theta1 * X)
    hidden = vstack((np.ones((1,m)),hidden))

    print sigmoid(theta2 * hidden)
    return np.argmax( sigmoid(theta2 * hidden),0 ).T + 1
```

I want to use this multiclassifier to classify the handwritten digits which has already been transferred as numbers (the original images are just simply binary pixel which means that 1 represents a pixel is pure black otherwise pure white)

In practice, X stores the data in a form of numpy.matrix and has a dimention of n1 * m (row * collon), here n1 represents the number of input layer Nodes, and m is the number of data sets, and y stores the labels (results from 1 to 9), also in a form of numpy.matrix, and has a dimention of K * m (K is the number of labels which is 9 here, and m is also the number of dataset). By the way, I have cancelled the calculation for s in backPro.

when I put X,y,and alpha (learning rate) into the backPro and get the theta1 and theta2, I then use these two parameters calculate the output using the training set (Yes, it is just the training set), but find that the predictions for all the datasets are the same, here I mean exactly the same, I find it incredible..
and here is result:

```
from simpleneu import predict as pre
pre(X,theta1,theta2)
[[0.10106717 0.10106717 0.10106717 ... 0.10106717 0.10106717 0.10106717]
 [0.10169492 0.10169492 0.10169492 ... 0.10169492 0.10169492 0.10169492]
 [0.09981168 0.09981168 0.09981168 ... 0.09981168 0.09981168 0.09981168]
 ...
 [0.09918393 0.09918393 0.09918393 ... 0.09918393 0.09918393 0.09918393]
 [0.09730069 0.09730069 0.09730069 ... 0.09730069 0.09730069 0.09730069]
 [0.09918393 0.09918393 0.09918393 ... 0.09918393 0.09918393 0.09918393]]
Out[99]: 
matrix([[2],
        [2],
        [2],
        ...,
        [2],
        [2],
        [2]])
```

and the dimention of the output is K * m, and in the predict() function I print out the sigmoid(theta2 * hidden) before transferring them as the labels of ones with the largest potential

and here is the graph for J which is the cost with respect to iteration times:
[image]